# Breeze BeforeSaveEntities: how to modify savemap

Tags: breeze

I read the following from [the Breeze documentation about BeforeSaveEntities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider):

"Entities may be added or removed from the map returned by this method".

So I suppose I can add a new instance of EntityInfo to the saveMap.
My question is: how can I do that? Is there any example of that anywhere?

I can perfectly loop through the dictionary. But since EntityInfo has no constructor, and all its fields are get only, I feel a bit stuck here. Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just add the new object to your DbContext?

Comment: Well that's I'm doing right now. But then of course the call to SaveChanges in the Breeze controller returns a SaveResult with 0 entities in it. So I would like to know if it's actually possible to add something to saveMap, as suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, here is a very contrived example of a *BeforeSaveEntities* override that creates comment records alongside a whatever is normally saved.  Comment records include a comment generated based on the value of the *SaveOptions.Tag* property.

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type,   List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) {
    var comment = new Comment();
    var tag = ContextProvider.SaveOptions.Tag;
    comment.Comment1 = (tag == null) ? "Generic comment" : tag.ToString();
    comment.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    comment.SeqNum = 1;
    var ei = ContextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(comment);
    List<EntityInfo> comments;
    if (!saveMap.TryGetValue(typeof(Comment), out comments)) {
      comments = new List<EntityInfo>();
      saveMap.Add(typeof(Comment), comments);
    }
    comments.Add(ei);

    return saveMap;
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks! var ei = ContextProvider.CreateEntityInfo(comment); That was it! :) Thanks again

Comment: Jay, still having an issue here. I successfully add stuff to saveMap, and actually replace the list that was in there, by a list of another type, with converted elements. I hit the following exception: "Sequence contains no matching element". I traced it to GetEntitySetName in EFContextProvider.cs, var ospaceEntityType = ospaceEntityTypes.First(oet => oet.FullName == entityType.FullName); No idea why it happens though. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nicolas, could you provide a small solution demonstrating the problem? This way we can check exactly what's happening. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, please send the repro solution to breeze@ideablade.com

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I think I just figured out what I am doing wrong. I created a DTO DbContext for the metadata, and another one for the data. I was converting an entity from DTO type to type, and putting it in the saveMap. Could it be the issue here?

Comment: Nicolas, the best way to figure it out is looking at the issue in a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those developers that have chosen to use Database First using an  objectContext instead of Code First, and for Nicolas.

I found after using the Breeze Source Code in Debug that line 805 of the `GetEntitySetName` method (`cspaceEntityType = cspaceEntityTypes.First(et => et.FullName == entityType.FullName`)

I would get the error "Sequence contains no matching element"

I noticed inside my watch that `et.FullName` and `entityType.FullName` did not have the same namespace. This told my comrad and I that the edmx models namespace was not the same as the object context.

Go to your edmx model select right click inside the empty space and  select properties. ensure that the Namespace property is the same as your Object Context.

[image: Screenshot]