# saveChanges - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, entity, breeze

I am kinda new to breeze.js and i tough the idea was great but I am stuck a bit here; everytime my breeze controller tries to save it throws me a "Sequence contains no matching element" altough the json contains the data; I am using knockout to bind it to a bootstrap modal and everything seems to work find till saveChanges is triggered and throws me that error. the json seems to be correct (contains all changes), I am kind of stuck here; if you need some code please let me know

thanks in advance
jan

edit added code:

the controller

```
 [BreezeController]
    public class BreezeEntityController : ApiController
    {

         readonly BreezeEntityRepo repository = new BreezeEntityRepo();

         [HttpGet]
         public IQueryable GetEtCustomers()
         {
             if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
             {
                 Int32 idUser = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
                 Int32 idSstuser = Helpers.Extensions.GetSstCustomerId(User.Identity.Name);
                 return repository.Customers.Cast<EtCustomer>().Where(o => (o.IdMain.HasValue && o.IdMain == idSstuser) || o.IdUser == idUser).AsQueryable();
             }

             return null;
         }

        [HttpGet]  
        public string Metadata()  
        { 
            return repository.Metadata();  
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
        }  

    }
```

the json I am trying to save:

```
{
"entities": [{
    "IdSstCustomer": 12520,
    "IdAddressType": 40,
    "IdTitle": 10,
    "Lastname": "Lieferadresse",
    "Firstname": "Dummy",
    "Title": null,
    "Name": "Maximilian Jan",
    "Email": "test@test.at",
    "NLstop": null,
    "Phone": null,
    "Company": null,
    "UID": "",
    "Address": "Teststr 1",
    "Address2": null,
    "City": "Wien",
    "ZipCode": "1110",
    "State": null,
    "Country": "AT",
    "CreateDate": "2013-02-25T12:06:00Z",
    "CreateUser": 22,
    "UpdateDate": null,
    "UpdateUser": null,
    "ApplicationId": null,
    "UserId": null,
    "IdMain": 10080,
    "IdUser": null,
    "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "EtCustomer:#interfaceLibrary",
        "defaultResourceName": "tbl_sst_Customer",
        "entityState": "Modified",
        "originalValuesMap": {
            "Firstname": "Jan",
            "Lastname": "Maximilian Lieferadresse",
            "Address": "Wienerstraße 53a",
            "ZipCode": "4020",
            "City": "Linz",
            "Email": "test@test-vertrieb.at"
        },
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
            "propertyName": "IdSstCustomer",
            "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
    }
}],
"saveOptions": {}
```

}

also my entity model is within an external dll; could this be the reason?

regards jan

edit sorry here is the last piece of code, this is repository:

```
 public class BreezeEntityRepo
    {
        readonly EFContextProvider<FaEntities> _contextProvider =
  new EFContextProvider<FaEntities>();

        public IQueryable<EtCustomer> Customers
        {
            get 
            {
                return _contextProvider.Context.tbl_sst_Customer; 
            }
        }

        public string Metadata()
        {
            return _contextProvider.Metadata();  
        }

        public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
        {
            return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);  
        }
    }
}
```

the viewmodel is

```
   var vm = {
        people: ko.observableArray([]),
        hide: ko.observable(true),
        save: saveChanges,
        newEtCustomer: ko.observable(
          {
              Title: "",
              Firstname: "",
              Lastname: "",
              Email: "",
              Address: "",
              City: "",
              ZipCode: "",
              Country: ""
          }),
        addEtCustomer: addNewEtCustomer,
        editEtCustomer: editEtCustomer
    };
```

and the save is called

```
   function editEtCustomer(customer) {
        vm.save();
    }
```

tough the data is commited correctly back to the server side controller

regards jan

edit:

okay the stacktrace is

```
  bei System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   bei Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.GetEntitySetName(Type entityType)
   bei Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.ProcessSaves(Dictionary`2 saveMap)
   bei Breeze.WebApi.EFContextProvider`1.SaveChangesCore(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
   bei Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.OpenAndSave(SaveWorkState saveWorkState)
   bei Breeze.WebApi.ContextProvider.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle, TransactionSettings transactionSettings)
   bei WatShop.Models.Entity.BreezeEntityRepo.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Projekte\ProjekteWeb\WatShop\WatShop\Models\Entity\BreezeEntityRepo.cs:Zeile 33.
   bei WatShop.Controllers.BreezeEntityController.SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) in c:\Projekte\ProjekteWeb\WatShop\WatShop\Controllers\BreezeEntityController.cs:Zeile 44.
   bei lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

hope this helps

regards jan

Comment: 'Sequence contains no matching element' appears to be a C# / .NET issue, are you sure you aren't intercepting the changes somehow or that whatever method is your saveChanges in your controller is function properly?  Also, next to impossible to help without any code samples.

Comment: Hello,
I added the Controller Code as well as the JSON if you need the knockout.js vm tell me then i add it too; thanks in advance 
regards jan

Comment: And what is `repository.SaveChanges(saveBundle)` ?????

Comment: +1 on Slauma's comment, you have another layer there with additional logic in the repository.SaveChanges that you need to show.

Comment: I am sorry for this, I added the missing code
and thank you for your patience

Comment: It might help if you could provide the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: hello I added the full stack trace; i am sorry for the inconvenience I am causing but i simply cant get it to run 
regards jan

Comment: The problem is apparently here: https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi/EFContextProvider.cs in line 679 or line 684 which probably means that the type defined by `EtCustomer:#interfaceLibrary` is not found in EF's metadata. Is that type/namespace/assembly correct including capital/small letters? Is your `EtCustomer` entity derived from another entity?

Comment: well no its not derived from another entity; but as said it lies within a different assembly, interfaceLibrary but the model is within the assemblies main namespace; the spelling is correct also its loaded from the entity that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. I am using EDMX file generated by Entity Framework 4.0.

The problem is in the following lines:

```
// Old EDMX ObjectContext has empty OSpace, so we get cspaceEntityType directly
var cspaceEntityTypes = metaWs.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
cspaceEntityType = cspaceEntityTypes.First(et => et.FullName == entityType.FullName);
```

In my case `et.FullName` conatins values such as `"MyModel.Customer"`, but `entityType.FullName` contains `"My.CSharp.Namespace.Customer"`.

So it looks like comparison problem. A quick (and dirty) workaround is to use only partial, not FullName in coparison:

```
cspaceEntityType = cspaceEntityTypes.First(et => et.Name == entityType.Name);
```

UPDATE: If you do not want to change the BreezeJS code, change the EDMX namespace as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001434/174638

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error. Wish I had found this post sooner as I had to include the Breeze source and debug and fix.

My solution was to change the Namespace for the EDMX. As long as you are not doing any Entity SQL this will not affect your existing code base. Also you will not have to change the breeze code.

Change the EDMX Namespace from "[EntityModelName]" to C# namespace.

Breeze will then work perfectly.